# unable insert jpeg into filemaker db with pyodbc : HY011 ODBC Error

Tags: python, odbc, filemaker, pyodbc, unixodbc

I get this odbc error by trying to insert a JPEG into a FileMaker 14 database. When i run the same script against a MySQL for inserting a blob, there's no error. Inserting a text field does not produce an error.
Also i have no clue and cannot find a meaningful explanation for odbc error HY011...

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance!

The output when i type the code interactively :

Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 15:13:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> with open('Femke.jpg', 'rb') as f:
...  data = f.read()
... 
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/Library/ODBC/FileMaker ODBC.bundle/Contents/MacOS/fmodbc.so};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testContainer;UID=Admin')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("insert into testContainer (cont) values (PutAs(?, 'JPEG'))", pyodbc.Binary(data))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('HY011', '[HY011] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Attribute cannot be set now (0) (SQLPutData)')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the filemaker jdbc/odbc guide it clearly states that it is able to treat clob types by JDBC (page 33). For ODBC i could not find this in the document, so i suppose this is a FileMaker ODBC interface shortcoming.
I now use JDBC and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound redundant, but I'd start by double checking that the target FileMaker field is actually defined as a Container field. If not, that would readily explain this error. You might also want to check [this FileMaker help document](http://help.filemaker.com/ci/fattach/get/25392/1279819772/redirect/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNDMyMjIzMzYxL3NpZC9SOWl4X1VtbQ==/filename/Migrating%20xDBC%20to%20FM11.pdf), outlining some O/JDBC blob error messages and their reasons.

If neither of those help, I'd check the security settings in the FileMaker database to ensure that xDBC users are authorized to create and edit records in the target table and that the container field is set to allow this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but i double checked an neither of those are an issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is a complete a shot in the dark, but try changing

```
cur.execute("insert into testContainer (cont) values (PutAs(?, 'JPEG'))", pyodbc.Binary(data))
```

to

```
cur.execute("insert into testContainer (PutAs(cont,'JPEG')) values (?))", pyodbc.Binary(data))
```

Comment: This is confusing because you can find a lot of examples like the one you found on the net, but they are incorrect! I know for sure my syntax is the correct one, as i used JDBC instead now and it works. It is nice wanting to be helpful, but please check before you post other people's mistakes.